# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. Pop-Os 21.10 Gnome V40.4.0

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gnome

There seems to be a lot of similar questions to this. I looked at 5 of them on StackOverflow and a few elsewhere (e.g. https://discuss.pixls.us/t/solved-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found/17677) but none of the solutions worked. Everything is installed. Everything is up-to-date. Below is the output. Any and all help would be appreciated

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

[1]    9588 IOT instruction (core dumped)  streamdeck
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this specific software, but often the reason is an incompatible Qt version, like a Qt 6 application tries to load a library that needs Qt 5, or vice-versa, or the two Qt versions were configured differently.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following whithin in a shell:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<your_user_name>/anaconda3/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

This prepends the location used to lookup shared libraries by your Anconda installation.

Start your application within the same shell.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and resolved it by installing the below module :

sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing
`sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`